# Address out of bounds- while accessing pointer returned by strtok

Tags: c, pointers, strtok

In a thread , I'm reading input from a file using fgets().  fgets() gives me the buf and when I tokenize, the returned char pointer says address out of bounds

```
char buf[1024];
char data[1024];//for use of strtok
char* dptr = NULL;
memset(&data,0,sizeof(data));
memset(&buf,0,sizeof(buf));
if(NULL != fgets(buf,1024,fp))
{
    /*remove new line char from fgets input*/
    if(buf[strlen(buf)-1] == '\n')
    {
        buf[strlen(buf)-1] = '\0';
    }
    /*making a local copy of buffer for strtok use*/
    strncpy(data,buf,1024);


    /*Get value 1 */
    dptr = NULL;
    char* rs;
    dptr = strtok_r(data," ", &rs);
    if(dptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"incorrect file format\n");
        return -1;
    }
            /*dptr is not NULL but cannot access it even in gdb*/
    int temp = atoi(dptr);//accessing dptr here gives address out of bound error.
```

I think the there is some problem accessing data buffer using the pointer dptr. Not able to analyze it though. I tried tokenizing and accessing using sscanf and array element replace and this worked-

```
dptr = buf;
int i=0;
    while(*dptr != '\n' || *dptr != '\0' && i<1024)
    {
        if(*dptr == '\t')
        {
            buf[i] = '\0';

        }
        dptr++;
        i++;
    }
    char  v1[256],v2[256],v3[256];
    sscanf(buf,"%s %s %s",v1,v2,v3);
```

Comment: *`reading input from a file using strtok`* ??

Comment: Note that `strncpy` does not add a terminating \0 character if the source string is larger than the limit - in that case, and if your data does not contain a " ", `strtok_r` might read out of bounds

Comment: The src string has a terminating char.Have checked this in gdb. And after using strtok, I can see the data buffer replacing the first " " with /0. But the pointer strtok returns is giving segfault.

Comment: Did you check the string is terminated *within* 1024 bytes? Also, does it fail if you allocate `buf` and/or `data` with `malloc`? You might have hit you stack limit, maybe.

Comment: Please post a complete compiable example. It's impossible to debug a fragment. Also state your compiler, compilation flags, and OS flavour.

Comment: In any case, use `-Wall` and watch closely for warnings. Any implicitly defined function is a sign of potential trouble.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't include <string.h> before you call strtok_r, it will be implicitly declared to return an 'int'. If your pointers are a different size (as it is on a 64-bit machine), the return value will be sign-extended (or zero extended, I'm not sure) to 64 bits. This will result in an invalid pointer. You should include <string.h>.